# How can I set up a local DNS or proxy that uses OpenNIC for OpenNIC domains/TLDs, and Cloudflare (or any other) DNS for the rest?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, internet, dns-hosting

I've been pondering how to achieve this for the past few days. I love OpenNIC and everything they're doing, but sometimes the DNS servers are not always the best for normal, daily usage. While it's not often a problem, it's a nuisance.

I was wondering how I can go about setting up maybe a local DNS relay that will use if/else logic for specific TLD's.

Example: if tld = *.geek, *.o, *.bbs, *.bit (etc) use OpenNIC DNS, else use Cloudflare (or google or openDNS, etc).

I haven't been able to find a way to do this in a simple manner. Does anyone know of any GUI based tools that would do this? I have read in some places I might be able to do this using Bind9, but I haven't been able to find a straight answer regarding that either. I also thought about setting up a dns proxy but also can't find much on it..

Any tips, resources, tutorials or knowledge on this would be most appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! **Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations** are considered [**off-topic**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com. Potentially your question can be reworded or made suitable for the  [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange community, but before posting, please read their guidelines.

Comment: Technically what you ask for is of course entirely feasible and for example already supported in the versatile `dnsmasq` tool with the [`--server=/domain/ip-of-nameserver`](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html)  option

Comment: So using dnsmasq with that flag, how would I add each domain? Would I be able to use the --server flag more than once? Or is there a config file I can use. I just found this after looking up your recommendation, let me know if something like this should work fine https://old.reddit.com/r/selfhosted/comments/145prew/a_simple_dnsmasq_web_gui/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically what you ask for is of course entirely feasible and for example already supported in the versatile `dnsmasq` tool with the [`--server=/domain/nameserver`](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html)  options:

> **`S, --local, --server=[/[<domain>]/[domain/]][<server>[#<port>]][@<interface>][@<source-ip>[#<port>]]`**
> Specify upstream servers directly. Setting this flag does not suppress reading of `/etc/resolv.conf`, use `--no-resolv` to do that.
> If one or more optional domains are given, that server is used only for those domains and they are queried only using the specified server.
> This is intended for private nameservers: if you have a nameserver on your network which deals with names of the form `xxx.internal.thekelleys.org.uk` at `192.168.1.1` then giving the flag `--server=/internal.thekelleys.org.uk/192.168.1.1` will send all queries for internal machines to that nameserver, everything else will go to the servers in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

So set your default DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
#/etc/resolv.conf
server 8.8.8.8
```

And if your OpenNIC server IP-address is for example 192.0.2.2 start dnsmasq with the option `--server=/.geek/192.0.2.2  --server=/.bit/192.0.2.2`  to resolve all `.geek` and `.bit` domain names via OpenNIC.